# How to set Registry editor to root key

Tags: powershell

I have a scenario where , when I opened the regedit every time several times the registry hive must not be expanded . It should be set to root registry hive containing HKCR, HKCU, HKLM, HKCC irrespective of how many times the registry hives are opened and expanded. Can we achieve this?

Comment: Please can you show the specific piece of code that's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last key accessed by `regedit.exe` is stored on a per-user basis in:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Regedit
```

In a value named `LastKey`. You can set it to a value of `Computer` to have just the root node be selected on launch.

Create a shortcut that launches a powershell script to update said key before launching `regedit`:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Regedit -Name LastKey -Value Computer
Start-Process regedit
```